# DropDown options of array of objects

Tags: knockout.js

```
self.Questions = ko.observableArray([{QuestionId:1 , Value="Name"}]);
```

I have this Questions ObservableArray above

Is It possible to set the QuestionId and the Value as options in dropdown list

```
<select data-bind="options:Questions"></select>
```

when I try the select tag above it gives me [Object Object] in the options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only set 1 of the 2 as options: Value or QuestionId. And it's done using `optionsText` (which is what is displayed), and `value` (which is what is stored).

```js
var viewmodel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.Questions = ko.observableArray([{QuestionId:1 , Value:"Name"}]);
  self.selected = ko.observable();
};


ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options:Questions, optionsText: 'Value', value: selected"></select>
```

Read more [here](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html).